# I want Disable Action Pane Button from Enterprise Portal

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aot, enterprise-portal

I want Disable Action Pane Pane Button (here **View** Button) In **Enterprise Portal > Project > Project Invoice**

[EnterPrise Portal> Project > Project Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVchH.png)

I want to to hide View button from EP

**Tried Solution :**

I tried to **AOT> Forms> ProjInvoiceListPage> Design > Action Pane**

In this Property **Display Target Set to Client**, save and Deploy from **Menuitems > ProjInvoiceListPage and Deploy to EP** as shown in below image

[From AOT Property Display target as Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnVLd.png)

But Problem Remain Same, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caching problem of sharepoint, Ones I changed Display target of **Document Button group** to "**Client**" and deploy to EP and **restart** the server It works Fine,Because List page refer old one while accessing from EP before restart,so it happens